# WebView not rendering webpage

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, webkit

WebView is not rendering web page. I've passed webView and IWebResourceRequest as parameters to ShouldOverrideUrlLoading and it still doesn't seem to be working. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
{
var url = request.Url.ToString();


if (url.StartsWith("mailto:"))
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSendto, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));
    _context.StartActivity(intent);
    view.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Gray);
    view.Reload();
    return true;
}
else
    view.LoadUrl(url);
return true;
}
```

I've tried to use the correct parameters for `ShouldOVerrideUrlLoading` but it is not worked.

Comment: Did you double-check your url? Have you enabled Javascript? Does your webview handle redirect? There could be several reason for it to not display the page.

Comment: Yes, the shouldOverrideUrlLoading handles redirects whenever a new url is about to be loaded with webView. Javascript is also enabled

Comment: Please put your entire class here, this is very limited information